# How to understand Aalen additive regression model?

Tags: r, survival, cox-model

How to understand these plots with fits from an [Aalen’s additive regression model for censored data](https://rviews.rstudio.com/2017/09/25/survival-analysis-with-r/)?

[image: img]

I simply wonder why the curves change between plus and minus. Do they have to understand such that the y-axis is giving the influence in general and the behaviour over time how these specific components contribute?
Precisely: `celltypeadeno` would be the most significant part and `celltypesmallcell`, on the other hand, just reduces the other parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Aalen additive model that you show estimates, as functions of time, both the baseline hazard (`Intercept`) at reference values of covariates and the *additive* contributions of differences of covariate values from reference values to the hazard of an event. The covariate values can be either fixed in time or time-varying. If the model estimates that the contribution of a covariate to hazard changes from positive to negative over time, then "the curves change between plus and minus."

You'll see that most of "the curves [that] change between plus and minus" have wide ribbons, presumably confidence intervals, covering values of 0. Those probably represent nothing beyond noise for a covariate that has little association with outcome.

The coefficients for `celltypeadeno` and `celltypesmallcell` are differences from the reference level of `celltype` (`celltypesquamous` for this data set). As the `Intercept` is the hazard over time at reference levels of all covariates, the `Intercept` includes patients with squamous-cell tumors.

It's hard to tell what's going on with `celltypeadeno` from these plots, as its y-axis scale seems to be determined by a very large value at very late times that might not be representative. It's possible that `celltypesmallcell` is more strongly associated with outcome at early times; you'd have to expand the y-axis scale for `celltypeadeno` to compare.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I understood it, except of the very first sentence which is probably the most important one. So the covariates have a baseline and they change over time. And the Aalen model takes into account these changes by adding them, right?

Sounds like a usual regression model?

Comment: @Ben perhaps my use of "baseline" was ambiguous. I've changed that to "reference." This is essentially a set of regressions done at each event time. The intercept is the hazard when all covariates are at their reference values (e.g., 0 for continuous covariates, a particular reference level for categorical ones). Each coefficient at an event time is the difference in hazard per unit difference of the covariate from its reference level: one unit difference for a continuous covariate, or the difference of a categorical predictor from its reference level. That's similar to any regression.

Comment: Alright, thank you!