# Why is the hazard rate (from an Aalen model) subject to the number of levels of a factor / parameter?

Tags: survival, cox-model

As a follow up on [How to understand Aalen additive regression model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/569703/how-to-understand-aalen-additive-regression-model) I've conducted this method on my own data (which is, unfortunately, confidential). Hence, I cannot reveal what these data represent but I believe it doesn't matter, anyway.

[image: img]

[image: img2]

[image: img3]

You can see here the hazard rate(?) separated by country. I realized that the one country in the center in the lowest row (UK) has a quite high hazard rate. So I removed this country from the data just to check what happens. I figured out, that another country provided even larger rates then. So I removed this, too. And then two other countries had even higher values, than ever before.
What is going on? This doesn't seem robust to me?
I realized that

**edit**: Before I forget: For United Kingdom, there is only one subject. Other very "fragile" countries are Macedonia (with two subjects) or Czech Republic (with four subjects). In total, there are about 305 subjects.
The syntax of the fit is:

```
fit<- survfit(Surv(time, event) ~ country,
               data = df[df$country != "?" & df$country != "", ])
```

Comment: The display for a particular level of a categorical predictor is the estimated _difference in hazard from that of its reference level_, evaluated at each event time. The intercept is the hazard when all predictors are at reference levels. What you describe could happen with any type of multiple-regression model when you change the data set. The image is impossible to read and you don't show the differences between models that you describe in words, so it's hard to say much else. Please edit the question so we can see better what's going on, perhaps with a simpler model/data subset.

Comment: I replaced the image with bigger ones. The data is confidential, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aalen models are known to be unstable at the latest times, as there are few individuals left at risk for the regressions at each of the later event times. With a single UK individual whose event (if it happens at all) is at a very late time, this behavior isn't that surprising.

You also are probably overfitting your data. You evidently have 40 individual levels of a single categorical predictor (the reference level is what's shown in the Intercept). The usual rule of thumb in survival analysis is to have 10-20 *events* per coefficient that you are estimating. You should thus have 400-800 *events* for this model. If not all individuals experienced events, you presumably have fewer than 300 events. Such overfitting also can lead to the behavior that you describe, with high variability in predictions resulting from small changes in data. My sense is that this is even more of a problem in Aalen models with their repeated regressions at each event time, although I have almost no practical experience with them.

Comment: thanks a lot for all your support! May I simply ask how you would proceed in my case? It seems like you know enough of the field itself to pick a reasonable track.

Comment: @Ben much depends on just what you're trying to accomplish. If these examples resemble your actual data, you need to reduce the number of predictors, e.g. by grouping based on subject-matter knowledge, or use a penalized method like ridge regression. I would avoid Aalen additive models. Look at Frank Harrell's [course notes](https://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf) and [book](https://hbiostat.org/rms/) for guidance on how to deal with too many predictors and on survival modeling. I don't think that he covers Aalen additive models at all. Use other approaches (Cox models, fully parametric models).