# How to determine the lifetime?

Tags: survival, reliability, quality-control

I want to determine the average expected lifetime of devices of which I have data.
This data comprises ~4500 generators of which ~3800 died and the others are still alive. Furthermore, I have information of their production date and end of life, thus giving me a period of successful operation. Or, respectively, the time until they died.

Meanwhile, I'm aware of some methods, especially Weibull analysis and survival analysis (I think they are quite connected or maybe even part of each other.. Idk).

Could you please point me towards a meaningful direction, resp. which method(s) make(s) sense to dig deeper into?

Comment: Start with the links in [this comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/569882/why-is-the-hazard-rate-from-an-aalen-model-subject-to-the-number-of-levels-of#comment1051611_569893) in another of your threads. A survival function is just [1 minus a (cumulative) distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis#Lifetime_distribution_function_and_event_density). "Survival analysis" can thus apply to any 1-dimensional probability distribution. The question is which underlying distribution works on your data and can incorporate censoring and covariates correctly.

Comment: Meanwhile, I'm "simply" using cox regression which provides quite robust estimations. For other people seeking similar information: Cox is a standard model for survival analysis / lifetime estimations and there are certain assumptions which should be fulfilled when performing this model (I'm mainly using those which can be visualized as the numbers contradict each other in my case). Plus, you should be careful, when you include variables which change over time (like a patient who takes another drug after half of the study). Then it would be a time-dependent cox regression.